# Tomcat with https a non-root user - Bind exception 443

Tags: tomcat, bind

I want to run tomcat on port 443 with non-root user (https://machinIP). I'm getting below error:

```
Error initializing endpoint java.net.BindException: Permission denied:443
```

I don't have port 443 in use for sure. I read somewhere that we cannot use port 443 a non-root user & alternative is to use iptables but I'm not aware on exactly how to use iptables..

I'll appreciate if someone can give me the exact command of iptables & whether I need to make any changes in server.xml a well? Current server.xml uses port 8080 for http & port 8443 for https.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As non-root user you cannot bind on port 443. The server.xml contains the binding for the ssl port, which you have already mentioned is setup for 8443. Not sure where its getting 443 from. Do you have access to the conf folder ? Can you search for 443 and see if that reveals anything useful ?

Comment: Oh...Sorry for not clarifying it. I changed 8443 to 443 in server.xml since  I need to access my website at https : //IP How can I do it with non-root user

Comment: You can't, but you can use a proxy (apache for instance)

Comment: Proxy is one option and iptables is another. I have personally not tried out iptables for this particular setting but I googled it and its seems pretty straightforward. Following is one of the solutions.

http://distriwatch.de/2010/06/iptables-forward-port-8443-to-port-443/

Comment: I tried iptables by following above link & I didn't get any errors which is good thing. But, when I hit the URL https : //myip, I was getting "Page cannot be displayed", it was not even hitting the server & there was no log at all. What could be the reason? If I want to use another approach of using a proxy as Maurice mentioned, what do I need to do exactly? Can you please explain?

Comment: Is iptables even running on the server ? After running the iptables command mention in the link (as user root) you will need to startup iptables if it is not running. To startup iptables run the following command as user root 

"service iptables start". 

To check the status of iptables run 

"service iptables status"

Answer (score 0):

Its works for me :-)

```
 wget http://download.si-linux.co.jp/debian-mirror/squeeze_20120726/pool/main/a/authbind/authbind_1.2.0.tar.gz
```

unzip > CD  >  Make > make install

```
    sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/443
    sudo chmod 500 /etc/authbind/byport/443
    sudo chown <non_root_user> /etc/authbind/byport/443

    vim tomcat/bin/startup.sh
    exec authbind --deep "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@"
```